# I want to calculate the total work_time of DB

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I want the total working time when completion is selected.

**workController**

```
public function store(CreateWorkRequest $request, Project $project)
{
    $work = new Work;
    $work->fill($request->all())->save();
    $project -> fill(['status' => $request->status])->update();

    if($request->status === 'completed')
    {
        $alltime = $item->select('work_time')->get();
        $project -> fill(['total_work_time' => $alltime])->save();
    }

    return redirect()->route('work.index', ['project' => $project->id]);
}
```

But none of that works.

How do I find the sum of a particular column in a selected table?

I tried:

```
if($request->status === 'completed')
{
    $alltime = 0;
    $items =  Work::where('project_id', $project->id)->get();
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        $time = $item->select('work_time')->get();
        $alltime += $time;
    }
    $project -> fill(['total_work_time' => $alltime])->save();
}
```

But it didn't run as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get the total working time with the following query:

```
$totalWorkingTime = Work::query()
    ->where('project_id', $project->id)
    ->sum('work_time');
```

Comment: Was saved
Thank you